# Need explanation for output of "puts" in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, pointer-arithmetic, puts

I am looking for explanation for output of this code snippet. I have searched the Internet but could not find satisfactory explanation.

```
main()
{
     char x[10]="abcdefg" ;
     puts(&x[4]) ;
}
```

After executing this code, I got "efg" as the output.

Can you please explain this output?
And apologies if this platform is not for such questions.

Comment: `&x[4]` is the same as `x + 4`. Maybe `puts(x + 4);` is easier for you?

Comment: If you know that strings are usually seens a pointers to the first character in the string, and if you know which character `x[4]` is, then it should be easy to figure out what a pointer to `x[4]` (i.e. what's given by `&x[4]`) should be.

Answer (score 3):

&x[4] is the address in memory of element 4 of the character array x.
Which means puts is receiving "efg" as input.

Comment: I'd say element five!!

Comment: False.  Element *zero* is always the first element.

Comment: Yes, I was expecting so see that explicit mention not as a comment but in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to `C11`, chapter §7.21.7.9

> ```
> int puts(const char *s);
> ```
>
> The `puts` function writes the string pointed to by s to the stream pointed to by `stdout`, and appends a new-line character to the output. The terminating null character is not
>   written. [...]

So, in your case, you're passing the address of the fifth element in the array `x` (yes, C arrays use 0-based index), and the remaining elements in that string , until the terminating null is printed.